# Creating a new collection from results of a mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to create a new collection using the results of a mongodb query. For example,

```js
db.coll.find({name:'abcd'})
```

will return a subset of the collection. Now, I want to insert this result into a new collection. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this directly with `find`, but you can use an [`$out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) pipeline stage of `aggregate` to do it:

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
    {$match: {name: 'abcd'}},
    {$out: 'newcoll'}
])
```

Note that `$out` support was added in MongoDB 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note:
If you want include only particular fields from output - you can use `project` keyword, as:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {$match: {name: 'abcd'}},
    { $project: {'name': 1}}
    {$out: 'newcoll'}
])
```